# Why dose not delaysTouchesEnded delay touchesEnded:withEvent: for double tap gesture?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

With this code my view's `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` still gets called for the ***first*** tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
doubleTapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapGR.delaysTouchesEnded = YES;
doubleTapGR.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGR];
```

But according to the document of `delaysTouchesEnded` it should not:

> When the value of this property is YES (the default) and the receiver
>   is analyzing touch events, the window suspends delivery of touch
>   objects in the UITouchPhaseEnded phase to the attached view. If the
>   gesture recognizer subsequently recognizes its gesture, these touch
>   objects are cancelled (via a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message). If
>   the gesture recognizer does not recognize its gesture, the window
>   delivers these objects in an invocation of the view’s
>   touchesEnded:withEvent: method. Set this property to NO to have touch
>   objects in the UITouchPhaseEnded delivered to the view while the
>   gesture recognizer is analyzing the same touches.